# How would I match regex with a String of unknown length, but in a specific pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my regex for a string that can be any length but always follows the pattern below

```
"(A,B)" = valid
"(A,B) (B,C)" = valid
```

Basically, parenthesis "(", A-Z letter, comma, A-Z letter, parenthesis ")", a white space if and only if there the sequence begins again, otherwise no whitespace.

So far I've gotten to `"^\\([A-Z]?,[A-Z]?\\)*.\\([A-Z]?,[A-Z]?\\).*$"` but I'm not sure what about my regex is not working right.

Comment: Why are you putting a `?` after the `[A-Z]`? Also, because of the `.*$` at the end of the regex it looks like you want to match the whole string, even if only the first part of it has the e.g. `(A,B)` pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex,

```
^(?:\s?\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)(?:\s\([A-Z],[A-Z]\))?)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cGUxYW/1)

**Description:**

- `^`: Asserts position at start of a line
- `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group

  - `\s?`: Optional whitespace character
  - `\(`: The character `(`
  - `[A-Z]`: The character, `A` to `Z`
  - `,`: The character `,`
  - `[A-Z]`: The character, `A` to `Z`
  - `\)`: The character `(`
  - `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group

    - `\s\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)`: Pattern already explained above
  - `)`: End of non-capturing group
  - `?`: Makes the last non-capturing group optional
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `*`: Matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times
- `$`: Asserts position at the end of a line

#### A better solution (courtesy: [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)):

You can also optionally repeat n groups after the first match i.e.

```
^\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)(?: \([A-Z],[A-Z]\))*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV853O/1)

Comment: I think you can also optionally repeat n groups after the first match `^\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)(?: \([A-Z],[A-Z]\))*$` https://regex101.com/r/EV853O/1

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird for the suggested improvement.  Your solution is indeed better than mine. Please post your suggestion as an answer so that the OP can accept that.

Comment: You can add it to your answer if you want :-)

Comment: Saving this in case I have this issue again! Appreciate the help! Guess I was closer than I thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
([(]([A-Z])\,([A-Z])[)])(\s[(]([A-Z])\,([A-Z])[)])*

final String regex = "([(]([A-Z])\\,([A-Z])[)])(\\s[(]([A-Z])\\,([A-Z])[)])*";
```